# FIND_IN_SET with two strings

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I have this EMPLOYEE table of employees list

```
+-----+---------------+-------------+
| ID  |EMPLOYEE_ID    | SKILLS      |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  1  |       1       |   3,4       |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  2  |       2       |   3,5,2     |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  3  |       3       |  1,5        |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
```

and table POSTED_JOB listing jobs

```
+-----+---------------+-------------+
| ID  |POSTED_JOB_ID  |  JOB_SKILLS |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  1  |       1       |   1,2,3     |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  2  |       2       |   3,4       |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  3  |       3       |   5,4       |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
|  4  |       4       |   5,6       |
+-----+---------------+-------------+
```

How can I get all jobs posted with skills corresponding to the skills of employees with laravel query.

For example for employee with employee_id 1, the jobs would be 1,2, and 3.

I tried with find_in_set but here both are lists.
    DB::raw("find_in_set(EMPLOYEE.SKILLS , POSTED_JOB.JOB_SKILLS)"), DB::raw(''), DB::raw(''))

Comment: suggest normalising your data

Comment: @FirstOne A user wants to see  the jobs with similar skills mentioned by him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$skills = 'select the employee skills';
$skl_arr = explode(',',$skills);
$skl_length = count($skl_arr);
```

/*query */

```
$rows->orwhere(DB::raw("find_in_set('$skl_arr[0]','post_job.skills')"));

for ($i=1; $i < $skl_length ; $i++) { 
                $rows->$join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set('$skl_arr[$i]','post_job.skills')",DB::raw(''),DB::raw('')));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this over join

```
DB::table('POSTED_JOB')->leftJoin('EMPLOYEE', function($join){
   $join->on(DB::raw("find_in_set(POSTED_JOB.JOB_SKILLSmEMPLOYEE.SKILLS)"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to search in two columns.

```
SELECT * FROM order1 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(order_no,'$foo') OR awb_no IN ('$foo')
```